# How to select all children from XML in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have the below XML when I run the select query it considers only the first value, what I am missing here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <string>1</string>
  <string>2</string>
  <string>3</string>
  .............
</ArrayOfString>
```

Below query only returns 1, I am expecting it to return all values like 1,2,3...

```
SELECT xmlu.v1.value('string[1]', 'BIGINT')
                                    FROM
           @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfString')
           AS xmlU(v1)
```

Comment: *"considers only the first value"* Because that's what you asked for: `'string[1]'`; the `[1]` means the first node. Are you saying you want delimited results?

Comment: @Larnu, no I want in multiple rows only. actualy I want to use the result in a where clause. like this `where id in (SELECT xmlu.v1.value('string[1]', 'BIGINT')
                                    FROM
           @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfString')
           AS xmlU(v1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one row per `string` node, you need to include the `string` node in your `nodes` clause:

```sql
SELECT AOS.s.value('(./text())[1]','bigint') AS string --If it's string, why are you asking for a bigint?
FROM (VALUES(@XML))V(X)
     CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('/ArrayOfString/string')AOS(s);
```

Comment: is this ok to use in this way? I mean performance wise. there can be 100 string children

Comment: I have full control over creating the XML variable from code and pass to the stored procedure. so please advise, is this the right way of passing the XML? or do I need to change the XML schema? so my only intention is to pass multiple values to the stored procedure.

Comment: *"is this ok to use in this way?"* Why wouldn't it be "ok"; 100 rows is literally nothing to an RDBMS.

Comment: *"so my only intention is to pass multiple values to the stored procedure"* Why not use a table type parameter, @viveknuna , if that is your *true* goal?

Comment: I had used table variable in past and my experience is bad, and I observed that XML is faster than the variable, is it not the case? So shall I use the table variable, not the XML?

Comment: I would suggest a table type parameter would be a better choice over `xml` yes, however, that is a **completely** different question. If you want to ask about the benefits of use a TTP over XML you should ask a new question, @viveknuna .

Comment: You don't need to `CROSS APPLY` if you only have one value, you can just `FROM @XML.nodes(...`

Comment: I know, @Charlieface, it's more preference and *normally* the XML is coming from a table column not a variable. I have lost count how many times I have used `FROM @XML.nodes` to have people tell me "but this isn't working: `FROM dbo.MyTable.XMLColumn.nodes`" /sigh

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for something like the following.

It is better not to use the `IN` clause because it usually gets converted to inefficient **OR** expressiions.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, city VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @tbl (city) VALUES
('Miami'),
('Orlando'),
('Dallas'),
('New York'),
('Hollywood');

DECLARE @parameter XML =
N'<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <string>1</string>
    <string>2</string>
    <string>3</string>
</ArrayOfString>'
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('.', 'INT') AS ID
    FROM @parameter.nodes('/ArrayOfString/string/text()') AS t(c)
)
SELECT * 
FROM @tbl AS t INNER JOIN 
     rs ON t.ID = rs.ID;
```